# Reducers for dynamically created items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Is there any particular "good practice" in Redux when it comes to reducing state of dynamically created items? In this particular case, I'm dealing with a list of users that may join/leave the app, tables and games at any time.

```
let userReducer = (user, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'table:create':
        case 'table:join': return {
            ...user,
            tables: [...user.tables, action.tableId]
        }
        case 'table:leave': return {
            ...user,
            tables: user.tables.filter(tableId => tableId != action.tableId)
        };
        case 'game:join': return {
            ...user,
            games: [...user.games, action.gameId]
        };
        case 'game:leave': return {
            ...user,
            games: user.games.filter(gameId => gameId != action.gameId)
        };
    }
}

let usersById = (users = {}, action) => {
    let user = users[action.userId];

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'user:join': return {
            ...users, 
            [action.user.id]: action.user
        };
        case 'user:leave': {
            users = {...users};

            delete users[action.userId];

            return users;
        };
        case 'table:create':
        case 'table:join':
        case 'table:leave':
        case 'game:join':
        case 'game:leave': return {
            ...users,
            [action.userId]: userReducer(user, action)
        };
    }

    return users;
}
```

The last five cases in the second function's switch statement look particularly ugly to me. Maybe I could just condense it with an if? (if user is defined, then apply userReducer to it).

```
let usersById = (users = {}, action) => {
    let user = users[action.userId];

    if(user)
        return {
            ...users,
            [user.id]: userReducer(user, action);
        }

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'user:join': return {
            ...users, 
            [action.user.id]: action.user
        };
        case 'user:leave': {
            users = {...users};

            delete users[action.userId];

            return users;
        };
    }

    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the contrary, that looks like some fairly well-organized reducer logic.  But yes, if you want to use an `if` statement like that, you absolutely can - per the [Redux FAQ on using switch statements](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Reducers.html#reducers-use-switch), it's fine to use whatever logic approach you want in a reducer.

For more information on ways to organize reducer logic, see the [Redux docs section on "Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html), and my recent blog post [Idiomatic Redux: The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/)

Comment: Thank you. Great articles by the way. Just a question, can you point me to an example of the connect short-hand syntax you mention?

Comment: Sure.  It's just `connect(mapState, {actionCreator1, actionCreator2})(MyComponent)`.  I've got some examples in my post [Idiomatic Redux: Why Use Action Creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/), and also make use of it in my ["Practical Redux" tutorial series](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux/) and accompanying ["Project Minimek" sample application](https://github.com/markerikson/project-minimek).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any good practice in order to create reducers.

Personally I rather use the approach of your first exemple, as it make your code more readable. In addition it will allow you to keep the same structure to all your reducers.